# Expected number of turns or rolls to end "death roll" game

Tags: probability

In the game World of Warcraft, I came across this game called "death rolling". (See similar post here [Death rolls - 50/50?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963207/death-rolls-50-50)).

The game has $2$ players. The first player types /roll $N_0$ which generates a random integer $N_1$  in the interval $[1,N_0]$. The second player similarly generates a random integer $N_2$ in the interval $[1,N_1]$. This process continues iteratively alternating between Player 1 and Player 2 until one of the players rolls $1$, and this player is deemed the loser of the game.

What is the expected number of rolls $m$ in this game in terms of $N_0$?

**EDIT**: I think this question is actually a duplicate with [Average Length of Random Number Generation with Decreasing Range of Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3716599/average-length-of-random-number-generation-with-decreasing-range-of-numbers?rq=1) . The answer provided there makes pretty good sense, but I don't quite follow the final step. Can anyone help me understand their justification for the final step?

Comment: Just to clarify, it is possible for a player to roll the same result as the player before them, right? So the game could, theoretically, never end.

Comment: Yes. That is possible.

Comment: This makes me wonder how much the answer changes if we exclude that possibility though. Practically, this could be as simple as excluding the right endpoint and considering $[1,N_i)$ instead of $[1,N_i]$ in each iteration.

Comment: No, nothing yet and I am aware.

Comment: A quick check of small cases and a search leads me to suspect that the answer is [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A000774), divided by $N_0!$ (except for $N_0=1$, which is expected to take 0 rolls, because then it's already over as that means the "previous" player rolled a 1; a small abstraction sacrifice to make things a little tidier). I have no idea whether that holds up past $N_0=5$. And also, I may have made mistakes, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: That is very interesting. I will test it out empirically! :)

Comment: What exactly don't you understand in the "final step"?

Comment: I just don't see how they get there. I tried some algebraic manipulations and couldn't see how they changed the denominator.

Comment: Here's a [live Sage / Python sim](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlkdtuwyAMhu_zFFZ2A2rWhO4kRULa1Z5iUuU1TssaoALy_gOaNE3nKx8-_7bs3lkNKpAL1g4elL5YF-BgRxOKPtUcmi4h14In6qqcUxFIEXvd8aL4jCE5PISiox40KsO0FLuX949Ij8ZL0TRNBTgGux8vHQaSXzh44m0B0S4u9rMynMg6CuqAQ1tWwMSGxoHc_ohaI2xgsEemnwWPbrN9q7PPt4ZxnlWCDSChyX5vHfyCMmnXIzHRTJOS-Rs1k2oh07Z3bLKTig16lXqaVlYVkOlk2ULJV0BSPSfVfEomHiRvstMpmahizP8x85zTPKh6HJRM9VlMgmjhxxGe17tO1_02sfu87vawkbDgGDcyzEOdn7agVwVcEunUsRPvv6cJTXpbqtUQL_4HRuiZFQ==&lang=sage) that incorporates Henry's formula.

Comment: The linked question has $f(N_0)=\frac1{N_0}(1+f(N_0))+\frac{N_0-1}{N_0}f(N_0-1)$  which implies $\frac{N_0-1}{N_0}f(N_0)=\frac1{N_0}+\frac{N_0-1}{N_0}f(N_0-1)$ and so $f(N_0)=\frac1{N_0-1}+f(N_0-1)$ and thus $f(N_0) = \frac1{N_0-1}+\frac1{N_0-2}+\cdots+\frac12+f(2) = H_{N_0-1}+1$ since $f(2)=2$

Comment: Thank you for being honest and finding the duplicate. For your updated question, please ask a new question so that you can describe it in more detail.

Comment: @Henry This is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $M_{N_k}$ is the random number of rolls for a starting value of $N_k$, then $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[M_{N_k}] 
&= 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{N_k} \operatorname{E}[M_{N_{k+1}}]\Pr[N_{k+1} = j] \\
&= 1 + \frac{\operatorname{E}[M_{N_k}]}{N_k} + \frac{1}{N_k} \sum_{j=1}^{N_k - 1} \operatorname{E}[M_j].
\end{align}$$
Consequently, for all $N_0 > 1$, $$\operatorname{E}[M_{N_0}] = \frac{N_0}{N_0 - 1} + \frac{1}{N_0 - 1} \sum_{j=1}^{N_0 - 1} \operatorname{E}[M_j]$$  with $\operatorname{E}[M_1] = 1$.  This yields the table
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
N_0 & \operatorname{E}[M_{N_0}] \\
\hline
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 \\
 3 & \frac{7}{2} \\
 4 & \frac{23}{6} \\
 5 & \frac{49}{12} \\
 6 & \frac{257}{60} \\
 7 & \frac{89}{20} \\
 8 & \frac{643}{140} \\
 9 & \frac{1321}{280} \\
 10 & \frac{12169}{2520} \\
 11 & \frac{12421}{2520} \\
 12 & \frac{139151}{27720} \\
 13 & \frac{141461}{27720} \\
 14 & \frac{1866713}{360360} \\
 15 & \frac{1892453}{360360} \\
 16 & \frac{1916477}{360360} \\
 17 & \frac{3877999}{720720} \\
 18 & \frac{66646703}{12252240} \\
 19 & \frac{22442461}{4084080} \\
 20 & \frac{430490839}{77597520} \\
\end{array}$$

At this time, I do not have a closed form solution, nor am I aware one exists; however, I suspect the asymptotic behavior to be something like $$\operatorname{E}[M_{N_0}] \sim c + \log N_0$$ for some suitable constant $c$.

---

Edit.  I now think that the closed form is $$\operatorname{E}[M_{N_0}] = 2 + H_{N_0-1},$$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.  Substitution into the recursion relation yields the desired result.

Comment: I think all your answers may be $1$ more than the actual values except the first which is a special case

Comment: I agree with @Henry. I get, for example, the recurrence equation $E(2)=1+{1\over2}E(2)$, implying $E(2)=2$. I agree that $N=1$ is a special case, and you should use $E(1)=0$ instead of $E(1)=1$.

Comment: I agree with @BarryCipra While $E(M_1)=1$ might make sense, in the recursion, you need to use $E(M_1)=0.$ That’s because the game stops then.

Comment: One way to make sense of $E(1)=0$ is to think of $E(N)$ as the expected number of times you *need* to roll the die in order to determine the final outcome. (If the "die" starts with only one face, you know you're going to be dead, so there's no need to roll it.)

Comment: But I definitely get that it is exactly $E(M_n)=1+H_{n-1}.$

Comment: Alternatively, rather than redefining $E(M_1)$ you could just change the sum in the recursion to $$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} E(M_k).$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the game continues, on any roll, is $\frac{N_1-1}{N_1}$. The probability that it ends is $\frac{1}{N_1}$.

You can use the above to get the probability that the game ends on turn $x$.  It has to not end, not end, not end, $x-1$ times, and then end on the last turn.  Then you can plug into the summation formula.  To calculate the expected value, you need to find $\sum x p(x)$.

Comment: Whereby $N_1$ is dependent on what you landed on the last turn....

Comment: The range of possible roll results shrinks (or at least, likely shrinks) every turn.

Comment: Thank you, @ShubhamJohri I misread that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the answer by heropup, call $a_n = E[M_n]$, giving the recurrence:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= \frac{n}{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} a_k
\end{align*}$

Write as:

$\begin{align*}
  a_{n + 1}
    &= \frac{n + 1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{1 \le k \le n} a_k
\end{align*}$

Multiply by $n$, subtract the expression for  $a_n$ from the one for $a_{n + 1}$ to get rid of the troublesome sum:

$\begin{align*}
  n a_{n + 1} - (n - 1) a_n
    &= (n + 1) - n + a_n \\
  n a_{n + 1} - n a_n
    &= 1
\end{align*}$

The last one is a linear recurrence of the first order. Add the initial condition $a_1 = 1$ this gives:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n - a_{n - 1}
   &= \frac{1}{n} \\
  a_n
   &= \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k}
\end{align*}$

This is just the harmonic numbers:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= H_n \\
    &= \gamma + \ln n + O(1/n)
\end{align*}$

where $\gamma = 0.5772156649$ is the Euler constant.